# Scheduling Report Emails to clone of "Customer Portal Manager Custom" profile not working

Tags: email, reporting, profile, scheduled

Scheduling Report Emails to clone of **Customer Portal Manager Custom profile** is not working. This cloned profile has both, `Run Reports` and `Export Reports`, **enabled**, not that it should matter because: the report is scheduled to run as a System Administrator user. I am receiving the following error message in my email:

> Salesforce.com could not email the report to any of the specified
>   recipients. Check that recipients are specified and that they have the
>   appropriate permissions to view the report.

What should I do?

EDIT: The email is scheduled outside the login hours of that profile. Is this happening because that profile doesn't have login hours set during the time of scheduled email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer. It is not that obvious, since you can select portal users as recipients of the scheduled report, even if the below checkbox is unchecked.

[image]